# The code is not indented

Tags: indentation

a program to display the numbers indivisible by 5 but not 7

```
 for i in range(2000,3201):
if i%5!=0 and i%7==0:
    print i

else:
    continue
```

Identationerror: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
specifically on line 5, the else statement

Comment: The answer to your question is literally in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for i in range(2000,3201):
  if i%5!=0 and i%7==0:
    print i
  else:
    continue
```